# Integer value with comma separated not getting saved to core data in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsnumberformatter

In my iPhone app am saving data to core data. I have to save one comma separated integer value.

```
NSNumberFormatter * formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:0];
NSString * newString =  [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:       [textField.text intValue]]];
textField.text=newString;
```

In textfield its displaying properly. But when I'm saving `[textField.text intValue]`, getting only first part before comma.

For example: If the text is 15,000 while saving am getting only 15. Please help!!!

Comment: This cases use String as property in coredata to store 15,000(these kind of format values)

Answer (score 3):

you want `[formatter numberFromString:textField.text]`, not `[textField.text intValue]`

Answer (score 0):

The value can be extracted by replacing the comma. 
Use

```
yourCommaString = [yourCommaString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""];
```

Now convert it to required integer value.

```
[NSNumber numberWithInteger:yourCommaString.integerValue]
```